# Counter example for The Composition Theorem for Riemann Integrability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, examples-counterexamples

Based on The Composition Theorem (found in the last Lemma [here](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~rchen/Advanced%20Calculus/Lebesgue%20Criterion%20for%20Riemann%20Integrability.pdf))) we can say that if a function *f* is Riemann Integrable, then $f^n$ is Riemann Integrable as well.
The converse is not true, but I can't think of a counter example, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, but $f(x)^2$ is the constant function $1$, hence is integrable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to come up with something along these lines, where -1 is involved and if we square it we'll get a constant function.